# Could the intraclass correlation coefficient be negative?

Tags: anova, intraclass-correlation

I'm a little confused regarding the intraclass correlation coefficient   I am now reading  "Face to Face interviews " by loosveldt 2008 . He pointed out on page 218 that the  intraclass correlation coefficient could be negative . 
Screenshot of the page

[image][image] .

Could someone explain  how the intraclass correlation coefficient could be negative ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please note that it is the *estimate* that can be negative - not the intraclass correlation itself. A common way to obtain the estimate of the numerator is via the method of moments -- in simple one-way anova cases this involves $MS(between)-MS(within)$. This difference will turn out to be negative whenever the $F$ ratio for the "between" effect is less than $1$.

Comment: Although I agree that the excerpt in the question is talking about the *estimate* being negative, I hope you're not implying here that the *estimand* must also be non-negative?

Comment: @JakeWestfall - Exactly. The estimand -- intraclass correlation -- is always non-negative.

Comment: But that's just not true. The lower bound of the ICC is -1/(m-1) where m is the number of times each unit is measured. It approaches being non-negative as m increases, but in real data it can certainly be negative. For small m it can even be substantially negative. Classic example is asking both members of married couples to estimate % of housework they typically complete: generally, the higher one's guess, the lower the other's guess, leading to strong negative ICC. Why do you say that the ICC must be non-negative?

Comment: @JakeWestfall - I misread your earlier comment. Yes, I definitely did mean to imply that the true ICC must be nonnegative. It is a variance divided by the sum of two variances. Variances can't be negative. Your latest comment is about the estimate -- not the estimand.

Comment: No, my comment is about the estimand, which I claim can be and sometimes is negative. The definition of ICC in terms of variance components is due to a random effects model framework -- it's a nice definition because it's simple, but it is decidedly a deficiency that this framework cannot conceive of negative ICCs. More complex/classical definitions avoid this issue, as they should. It's all laid out pretty nicely on the wiki page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intraclass_correlation

Comment: @JakeWestfall I'm appreciating your comment more and think it adds valuable insights. I had been thinking too narrowly in terms of the classical "model II" and the words "in real data" and distracted me from what you were really saying.